# Hadoop fs relates to generic filesystem supported by hadoop But hdfs dfs related to hdfs only

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Hadoop fs relates to generic filesystem supported by hadoop But hdfs dfs related to hdfs only.

Then why following command is allowed

> hdfs dfs -ls file:///

How can I access localfilesystem using hdfs dfs ?

Comment: No I don't think `hdfs dfs` is for HDFS only, it can work with any DFS compatible file systems, as long as it is configured to `fs.defaultFS` and `fs.default.name`. If I understand your question correctly...

Comment: Hi Weiwei,
Local filesystem isn't distributed filesystem. So how can I access it with hdfs dfs ?

Comment: Please take a look at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem, this is the class shipped in HDFS that implemented FileSystem API. When you use file:/// schema, it will be handled by this class. That's how you access local file system from hdfs commandline.